# What are other good websites for different styles of questions?

Tags: websites

This website in incredibly useful and it's already helped me a lot. However when it comes to asking questions about specific details/genres or questions that are heavily opinion based, sadly, this website doesn't work so well.

**Examples**

- If I were to ask what the blast radius of a small bomb was, I doubt I would be allowed to ask here.
- Similarly, I wouldn't be allowed to ask whether post-apocalypse survivors would be able to set up their own solar field without instructions.
- I can't ask what people think is the best form of dystopian governement is (opinion based).

I've tried searching already and haven't been able to find anything - I actually didn't find this one either, it was pure chance. If anyone has any useful websites that would be really helpful. I would just do lots of research but I feel like the police would give me a call if I kept on searching up questions about bombs.

Comment: Regarding your first example, I typed "bomb blast radius calculator" into Google and found [this](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/blast-radius).

Answer (score 2):

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ addresses a lot of questions related to creating a plausible world in which to set your writing.

I also recommend https://www.scribophile.com . It's primarily a critiquing site, but there are multiple communities of active writers who post there.

Answer (score 2):

One part of the answer is, other SE channels. Chris Sunami mentioned the Worldbuilding channel, which is good for figuring out hypothetical settings; the question about bomb blast radius would more properly belong someplace like Chemistry SE. As a rule of thumb, if you can't find the answer on your own, which is what you should try to do first, research questions for writing purposes are generally better asked at the respective channel that deals with the given topic (if such a channel exists), where you find the people who know the stuff, rather than here at Writing.